# How to display table data in Bold or color using jsp, javascript, css

Tags: javascript, java, css

I have a web application which displays data from a database. It shows results in 0's or numbers. The numbers displayed should be bold or in some color. How do i do I display the results from database in bold in a webapplication.

```
<svp:tbody rowCount="0" maxDisplayRows="100">
                                    <logic:iterate id="Typ" name="Typ">
                                        <logic:iterate id="ordType" name="ordTypes">
                                            <TR>
                                                <TD style="font-size: 9px"><bean:write name="Type"
                                                        property="TCode" /></TD>
                                                <TD style="font-size: 9px"><bean:write
                                                        name="Type" property="descr" /></TD>
                                                <%
                                                    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                                                                                String idStr = i + "_order";
                                                %>
                                                <TD style="font-size: 9px"><INPUT class="inactive"
                                                    readonly="readonly"
                                                    id="${Typ.TCode}_${oType.OTypCode}_<%=idStr%>"
                                                    type="text" size="10" value="0"></TD>
                                                <%
                                                    }
                                                %>
                                            </TR>
                                        </logic:iterate>
                                    </logic:iterate>
                                </svp:tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

your question doesn't have much of a context, so all I can suggest is

```
<td><b>value</b></td> //if you are using tables
```

`b` tag is for making font bold

you can also use

```
<td style='font-weight:bold'>value</td> //if you are using tables, css style
```

you can also use

```
<td class='bold'>value</td> //if you are using tables, css style

.bold //css class definition here
{
   font-weight:bold
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But am getting the data from the database. The data returned from the database should be displayed bold.

Comment: @user2821894 can you share how are you generating the table? you simply need do ensure while creating the table that values are in bold.

Comment: I mean I get values as 0's and some numbers like 123, 456. The numbers should be displayed as bold or some colors but not zero's

Comment: @user2821894 from here onwards, i don't know if I can really help you without knowing your code. Perhaps you can share what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I have edited my question with the code above

Comment: @user2821894 I am unable to understand you code as is, but why can't you check if the value is 0 (then don't do bold), or not (then do bold)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99341/discussion-between-user2821894-and-gurvinder372).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really messy, but from what I could understand, I'll try and help.

Lets say you have a `<td>` with a certain value you want to make bold? Add a *style* attribute to the td with "font-weight:bold;", making it from (for example) `<td>` into `<td style="font-weight:bold;">`

If you want to make only non-zero numbers in bold, use the `condition?<what to return when true>:<what to return when false>`:

```
int numberThatYouPut = ...;
<td>
    <%=numberThatYouPut!=0?"<b>"+numberThatYouPut+"</b>:numberThatYouPut%>
</td>
```

Comment: you got me right. Could you please tell me how do I apply the above to my code. The following is the piece of code from which i get the result. <TD style="font-size: 9px"><INPUT class="inactive"
                                                    readonly="readonly"
                                                    id="${Type.TypeCode}_${ordType.OrdTypeCode}_<%=idStr%>"
                                                    type="text" size="10" value="0"></TD>

Comment: I mean where do I apply the logic you gave in my code.